# Displaying the records from a mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am just starting to learn how to write stored procedures in MYSQL and I've hit a roadblock.

I wrote the following code:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `emscribedx`.`countcodes` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `emscribedx`.`countcodes` ()
BEGIN
declare doneprocessing int default 0;
declare thisaccount varchar(50);
declare countcursor cursor for select acct from patientid where patienttype='P';
declare continue handler for not found
set doneprocessing = 1;
Fetch countcursor into thisaccount;
Repeat
select * from doc_table where acct = thisaccount;
until doneprocessing = 1
END repeat;
close countcursor;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

I would like to display the results of the select statement that occurs after the repeat statement.   But how do I do that?   When I execute the stored procedure, nothing happens?

Thank you,

Elliott

Answer (score 0):

The procedure can only return the results of a single query, why not use this instead?

```
SELECT doc_table.* 
FROM doc_table 
INNER JOIN patientid
ON patientid.acct = doc_tableacct
WHERE patientid.patienttype='P';
```

It can be put inside of a procedure if you want.

Comment: This is just a toy procedure.    I'm experimenting with this just to get my feet wet with this stuff.   I want to know how to return these results.

Comment: If your procedure contains a single `SELECT` statement, it will return the query results when it's called. If it contains more than one `SELECT`, it will return the first one (if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: @bfavaretto: That's not entirely correct.  MySQL will return the results of every statement executed within a stored procedure, but the client may not support reading such multiple resultsets: with PDO, for example, one would call [`PDOStatement::nextRowset`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.nextrowset.php) to move between them.

Comment: @eggyal, Thanks for that info, I thought that was a serious problem in mysql. In the command line client, it works. In Workbench, it doesn't. Do you know if it works from PHP with the PDO driver?

Comment: @eggyal, Ooops, I'm really tired, I guess it's time to shut down! Thanks.